# Building library issue libudns

Tags: c, linux, configure

First of all thanks for your attention and help.

I have been trying to `./configure` and build a program that use a lot of libraries, and specifically libudns. I have been installing several libraries that were needed or by apt-get or by compile, and all of them works, but libudns (which is freaking me out).

This program make use of a **configure** script that include the following lines of code that add the flag `-ludns` to the **Makefile**:

```
if [ "x$WITH_UDNS" == "xy" ]; then
    mkl_lib_check "udns" HAVE_UDNS fail CC "-ludns" \
        "#include <udns.h>
        void *f();void *f(){return dns_init;}"
fi
```

When I type `./configure` the script checks if all libraries are presents on the system by *pkg-config* and by *compile*, as you can see in the following snap:

[image: Configure checks]

As you can see, configure cannot see this library.

What I have done is try to install this package by the two different ways:

1. By pkg-config: `sudo apt-get install libudns-dev`
2. By compile:

   `git clone https://github.com/shadowsocks/libudns`
   `cd libudns`
   `./autogen.sh`
   `./configure && make`
   `sudo make install`

With this two ways, I have both:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudns.so
/usr/local/include/udns.h
```

These paths are the same where others libraries are installed, for example PostgreSQL, which you can that is detected:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so
/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h
```

But the result is always the same:

[image: Building error]

Does anybody knows how to link this library?

Also, I have try these other things:

- Copy udns.h to /usr/include: `sudo cp /usr/local/include/udns.h /usr/include/udns.h`
- Make a sample program only to emulate this check:

  `#include <stdio.h>`

  `#include <udns.h>`

  `struct dns_ctx* ctx;`

  `void *f();
  void * f(){return dns_init;}`

  `int main(int argc, char** argv){`
      `int do_open = 0;`
      `printf("Hola, mundo\n");`
      `f(ctx, do_open);`
  `}`

And when I try to build this program with:

```
gcc main.c -o hello_world -ludns
```

it **WORKS**!?!

I have also try to build this program without the **-ludns** flag, and it gives me the same error as before:

[image: Sample program error]

So, I do not understand where is the fail, considering that as you can see in the second image, the **-ludns** flag is present.

Thanks a lot for your time. Any advise will be welcomed.

Comment: If it works from the command line and fails using the `Makefile` -- the problem is in the Makefile generation. If you are just compiling a single file, why worry about the Makefile at all? Yes, makefiles can do a lot of things for you when working with complex builds (but they require as much attention as your code to get right). If you just have one `libundns.so` (or `.a`) to like with your code, then just use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Ofast -o hello_world main.c -lundns`  Reserve makefile use for multi-source builds that make `gcc .... main.c other.c stillother.c` unworkable.

Comment: Maybe I haven't express myself right, but the single program is an example. The main issue is a bigger one that need several different sources and header files (also libraries).